# Warning: Ignoring extra legend entries in Matlab with several Y axes

Tags: matlab, plot, yaxis

I am drawing several plots on the same axis with the code like below

```
if isfield(data, 'yPredNew')
    yyaxis left;
    y = data.yPredNew;
    y = y(1:length(xx));
    h = plot(xx, y, '-k', 'LineWidth', 0.5);
    legend_labels{end+1}='yPred_{mixed}';
end
```

i.e. each plot can be either drawn or not depending on conditions. `legend_labels` arrays grows correspondently.

Until I have added `yyaxis` call there were no warnings. Then I have added `yyaxis` calls, some plots with `yyaxis left` others with `yyaxis right`. After that warning started to appear. Visually figure looks the same, but legend entries are mixed.

How to fix?

**UPDATE**

I think I fixed it by collecting legend entries separately for left and right in two arrays and then concating it before calling legend. This solved order. Warning was probably caused by enither error.

Comment: Can we get a screenshot of what happens before and after `yyaxis` is invoked?

Comment: The documentation for `yyaxis` doesn't mention legends. Back in the old days we had to overlay two axes to get this effect. This new function seems to do some odd things to get around syntax limitations too, for example you can only modify properties of the "currently selected" vertical axis. This is likely the cause of what you are seeing. Try plotting all left axis plots first, then the right axis ones, see if that sorts the legend entries?

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! [Answering your own question is not forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/4733879), but [officially encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)